# How to resolve a an Object Promise in this

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I cannot get a value to output in `:value="myFunction(cur_path)"` no matter what. It's always an `object Promise` even though I've tried different ways to await the value from the async function.  `async fetch_dpids(x)` gets data from the API, I call that function in another function called `async myFunction(x)` to `await` the value and output it through `:value=""` in the Vue HTML tags.

````
  <k-accordion>
    <k-accordion-item title="Best Paths">
        <div>
          <k-property-panel v-for="(path, index) in content">
            <k-accordion-item :title=format_title(index,path['cost'])>
              <k-property-panel-item v-for="(cur_path, path_index) in path['hops']"
                                     v-if="content" :name="String(path_index)" 
                                      :value="myFunction(fetch_dpids, cur_path)" 
                                      :key="path_index">
              </k-property-panel-item>
            </k-accordion-item>
          </k-property-panel>
        </div>
      </k-accordion-item>
  </k-accordion>
</template>
<!-- :name="String(path_index)" holds the # count;  
      :value="cur_path" holds the switch/interface; e.g. 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03
      -->
<script>
 module.exports = {
   props: ["content"],
   methods: {
    format_title(index, cost){
      return "Path " + index + ", cost: " + cost + ", hops: ";
    },
    
    async fetch_dpids(x) {
      try {
          const response  = await fetch('/api/myAPI/topology/v3/interfaces');
          const data      = await response.json();
          const dpids = Object.entries(data.interfaces).map(([key, value]) => {
            let item = key;
            if (item == x) { // troubleshooting
                console.log(item + "HERE <-------");
              }
            if (value.name) {
              item = `${value.name} - ${item} - ${value.mac}`;
            }
            return item;
          });
          this.dpids = dpids;
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
    },
    async myFunction(fetch_dpids, x) { //recent addition
      const result = await fetch_dpids(x);
      return result; // logs the resolved value of the Promise
  }
   }, // end of method block here
    
   data () {
     return {
       display: false,
       paths: [],
       headers: ["dpid"],
       rows: [this.content]
     }
   }
   
 }


</script>```

[Console log][1]
[object Promise][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpX7r.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msDgV.png
````